# An inequality concerning convexity and expectation

Tags: pr.probability, convexity, integration

Assume $f$ and $g$ are nonnegative with
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=1=\int_0^\infty g(x)dx
$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty xf(x)dx<\infty > \int_0^\infty xg(x)dx
$$
Is it true for nonnegative numbers $p$, $q$ with $p+q=1$, and $b\ge 0$ that

> $$
> p\int_c^\infty xf(x)dx + q\int_d^\infty xg(x)dx \le p\int_b^\infty xf(x)dx + q\int_b^\infty xg(x)dx
> $$

where $c$ and $d$ are defined by
$$
\int_c^\infty f(x)dx = \int_d^\infty g(x)dx = p\int_b^\infty f(x)dx + q\int_b^\infty g(x)dx ?
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this works. Let's say $c\le b$, so $b\le d$. Then (slightly rearranging) we want to show that
$$
p\int_c^b xf \le q \int_b^d xg \quad\quad\quad (1).
$$
Rearranging the definition of $c,d$, we see that
$$
\int_c^b f = q\int_b^{\infty}(g-f),\quad\quad
\int_b^d g = p \int_b^{\infty}(g-f) ,
$$
and this produces the identity $p\int_c^b f= q\int_b^d g$, which implies (1).

Comment: Yes, $x$ can be replaced by any (non-negative) increasing function.

Comment: I hope to eventually use this in a paper called "Nondeterministic automatic complexity of most words". Since I was stuck on this, perhaps you would accept to be listed as a coauthor.

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: I appreciate the offer, this is very generous. But I don't think my (small) contribution is substantial enough to be a coauthor. (I'm interested in the paper, would you mind sending me a copy when it's finished; for my e-mail -> my profile -> homepage.)